Cannot remove a mime type association in 24.04
I cannot remove an association for a file type (.hlp, which is a file type associated with the proprietary software Stata I use for work). When I select files of this type and <RIGHT_CLICK> then select "Open With…" I get no default file type. This is in itself strange, since /usr/share/mime/packages/stata-statamimetype_hlp.xml and stata-statamimetype_hlp.xml both exist, are readable, and declare:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="application/x-stata-hlp">
    <comment>Stata help file</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.hlp"/>
    <icon name="application-x-stata-hlp"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>

And the desktop file .local/share/applications/com.stata.xstata-mp18.desktop declares:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Comment=Perform statistical analyses using Stata.
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=application/x-stata-dta;application/x-stata-ado;application/x-stata-do;application/x-stata-sthlp;application/x-stata-smcl;application/x-stata-hlp;application/x-stata-gph;application/x-stata-stsem;application/x-stata-stpr;
Name=Stata/MP 18
Icon=/usr/local/stata18/stata18.png
Exec=/home/alexis/bin/.xstata-mp18.sh
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Education;Science;
Keywords=statistics;research;
Actions=doedit;use;view;graphuse;projmanag;semopen;
Hidden=false

Aside: Those other mime types (i.e. not .hlp files)? Those are all associated just fine with their respective file suffixes.
Back to "Open With…" when I scroll down the list of "Other Apps" Stata/MP 18 is not available. However, Stata/MP 17 is. "Ok," I think to myself, somewhere previous declarations associating Stata/MP 17 with the file suffix .hlp and the x-stata-hlp mime type remain present. So I go hunting recursively through /usr and /etc for files containing "stata-mp17" and "Stata\/MP 17" to change to "stata-mp18" and "Stata\/MP 18". Only, there are no mentions of the version 17. I do similarly to various system and user *.list files, where I found four needing change, either because they referred to version 17 or both to version 17 and version 18:
/usr/share/applications/defaults.list
.local/share/applications/defaults.list
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

Finally, I deleted all mime type declarations from .local/share/applications/com.stata.xstata-mp17.desktop. I rebuilt both the system and user mime types database using update-mime-database /usr/share/mime and update-mime-database .local/share/mime. I logged out and back in.
Still: "Open With…" on a .hlp files shows "Stata/MP 17".
How do I track down and eliminate the association of "Stata/MP 17" with the .hlp file extension and mime type?
BONUS: How do I get Ubuntu/Gnome to associate "Stata/MP 18" with the .hlp file extension and mime type? (Bearing in mind that it already does so for all the other stata-specific file extensions and mime types?!)
